# Looking for a clustering algorithm for highly noisy data

Tags: julia, data-science, cluster-analysis

I am trying to find clusters in some data with high noise (see plot below).

[image]

I tried using DBSCAN which sort of worked, but it required quite a bit of manually tuning the input parameters to find the clusters properly. Are there any other good clustering algorithms for dealing with this kind of data?

Some considerations:

- I am using Julia to do my data processing.
- The data has periodic boundary conditions in both directions.
- The number of clusters is known a priori.
- I am planning to process many datasets in this way, so it should run relatively fast and not require *too* much manual fiddling.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that OPTICS clustering can help you but I don't find way to do it in Julia. If you want to try in Python you can look here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.OPTICS.html .

Comment: There's a [Julia interface to scikit-learn called ScikitLearn.jl](https://github.com/cstjean/ScikitLearn.jl) through which you can access OPTICS (some models in the package are in Julia, some in Python, OPTICS  is currently imported from Python's scikit-learn). In case you happen to be using MLJ, there's also an [interface package](https://docs.juliahub.com/MLJScikitLearnInterface/OPmBR/0.2.0/autodocs/#MLJScikitLearnInterface.OPTICS) to use this model with the MLJ ecosystem.

Comment: I am not up to date with current algorithms, but in the past, someone might have brought up Kohonen networks. Basically you place a 2D grid of vertices (with 4 neighbors each) over your data space and then you pick random points from your data and move the closest grid vertex towards that point. The clustered regions, thus appear to attract a grid point and over time (not sure how fast it converges), the grid vertices move towards the clusters. It is easy to code and who knows, maybe you get lucky.

Answer (score 2):

I think the algorithm presented here https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.7130 could work for your problem. It is implemented in Julia here https://github.com/twMisc/Clustering-ToMaTo
I forked the project to refactor it as a package here
https://pnavaro.github.io/ClusteringToMaTo.jl
with some examples https://pnavaro.github.io/ClusteringToMaTo.jl/dev/demo2/

Perhaps you can put the code inside your project and adapt it. I hope it helps.

My objective is to offer this algorithm in a cleaner package https://github.com/pnavaro/GeometricClusterAnalysis.jl
but it is not finished yet.

Comment: The reference in https://github.com/twMisc/Clustering-ToMaTo is different from the one you linked to.

Comment: Yes sorry, the reference I gave is a variant. All references are avaible [here](https://geometrica.saclay.inria.fr/data/Steve.Oudot/clustering/).  I think the best implementation of these algorithms can be found in GUDHI project https://gudhi.inria.fr . They provide a R and a Python package.

Answer (score 0):

What about a generative/probabilistic model ? Maybe it doesn't fit your case, but you can try it very quickly:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("BetaML")
using BetaML
m       = GMMClusterModel(nClasses=K,mixtures=[FullGaussian() for i in 1:K])
fit!(m,X)  # X is a n by d matrix
classes = mode(predict(m))
```

Let me know!

Comment: Does GGM not assume more-or-less Gaussian clusters? Mine very much are not

Comment: I like the generative idea -- but yes, this looks more like uniform noise overlaying (non-Gaussian) clusters.

Comment: Your data as shown has non-Gaussian clusters, true, but that doesn't mean that a method with Gaussian clusters is an irretrievably bad match to the problem. In particular, doing two levels of clustering where each high-level cluster corresponds to the clusters you seek. These high-level clusters would, in turn, be defined as a mixture of Gaussian clusters. One way to build this up is to do a low-level clustering with Gaussians and then cluster those clusters based on overlap.